# Run a python module in a flask HTML template

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to decode an output from my database from base64 to text. here is a snippit my code:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, request, json
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'example'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'example'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'products_db'

mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from products;", mysql.connection.commit())
    data = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('products.html', data=data)
```

my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table border = 1>
    {% for product in data %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{product[0]}}</td>
        <td> {{product[2]}}</td>
        <td> {{base64.b64decode(product[3])}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to decode product[3] but im failing, how to do it on flask? how can i import other modules aswell?

thank you

Comment: @CDJB I'm new to FLASK and do not understand how to implement that solution to my code. I'm still learning how FLASK works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do base64 decode using jinja templating language. `base64.b64decode` is not supported in [jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/). You may do this on server side and pass the data to template.

```py
from flask import Flask,render_template, request, json
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'example'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'example'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'products_db'

mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from products;", mysql.connection.commit())
    data = cur.fetchall()
    modified_data = []
    for item in data:
        modified_item = []
        modified_item.append(item[0])
        modified_item.append(item[1])
        modified_item.append(base64.b64decode(item[3])
        modified_data.append(modified_item)
    return render_template('products.html', data=modified_data)
```

template index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table border = 1>
    {% for item in data %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{item[0]}}</td>
        <td> {{item[2]}}</td>
        <td> {{item[3]}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. When i run the code I get the following error:


TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: I made some to fix that error.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Your code only returns one record, is there a way to display the whole table? first column: ID second column: Name third column: DECODED_BASE64('dGVzdAo=')

Comment: How many records do you have in db?

Comment: im trying to include pagination with limit. each page has 5 records. total: 468 records.

Comment: what does modified_data contain before render? I think it should have more than one record.

Comment: problem solved, thanks. any resources you recommend to learn more about flask?

Comment: Miguel made some really nice tutorial about flask https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the function to the target data value before passing the returned database contents to `render_template`:

```
@app.route("/")
def main():
   cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
   cur.execute("select * from products;", mysql.connection.commit())
   data = [[*a, base64.b64decode(b)] for *a, b in cur.fetchall()]
   return render_template('products.html', data=data)
```

Now, in your template:

```
{% for product in data %}
  <tr>
    <td> {{product[0]}}</td>
    <td> {{product[2]}}</td>
    <td> {{product[3]}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Edit: Python2 solution:

```
data = [i[:3]+[base64.b64decode(i[3])]+i[4:] for i in cur.fetchall()]
```

Comment: Thank you. it is giving me an error regarding the star before the character "a" in the data variable.

Comment: @xiholac761 No problem, please see my recent edit. `*` can be used for unpacking, and is available in Python3 only. I added a solution for Python2.

Comment: thank you so much. flask has thrown me an error:     ValueError: too many values to unpack

could it be because too many letter? what do these letters represent if i may ask?

Comment: @xiholac761 The use of multiple comma separate variables in a `for` loop is called unpacking. I have updated the Python2 solution to better reflect your database content structure.